# Syntax error in MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

EDIT: I know the error is somewhere here:

```
$connection = @mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());

$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM authorize WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user_name]' and password = '$_SESSION[password]'";

$result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

$lstbalance = 0;
$balance = 0;

//set session variables if there is a match
if ($num != 0) 
{
    while ($sql = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
    {
    $lstbalance = $sql -> lostbalance;
    $balance = $sql -> balance;
    }
}

if ($win==true) 
{
$sql = "update users set lostbalance='($lstbalance+(($payouts[$result1.\'|\'.$result2.\'|\'.$result3])*(int)$_POST[\'bet\']))' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user_name]' and password = '$_SESSION[password]'";
}
else
{
$sql = "update users set lostbalance='(lstbalance-(int)$_POST[\'bet\'])' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user_name]' and password = '$_SESSION[password]'";
}
$result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

---

I was able to narrow down the error to this piece of code, help appreciated. Regards.

When I comment it out everything seems to work all the connect variables are from a different file and are valid.

Comment: It's a php error and it's probably not on that line.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Most of what you've presented here is not relevant and you've omitted stuff which would make it easier to debug.

What was the error message?

If it's a syntax error in the SQL satements, what do the interpolated SQL statements look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
$lostbalance = $lstbalance+(($payouts[$result1])*(int)$_POST['bet']));
$sql = "update users set lostbalance='$lostbalance' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."' and password = '".$_SESSION['password']."'";
```

i dont understand about ur code on $payout[$result1.\'|\'.$result2.\'|\'.$result3]